# Which of the z and w component outputs from the vertex shader can I modify without breaking the implementation?

Tags: graphics, shader

With the projection matrix the z value in camera/eye space is multiplied by (NEAR + FAR)/(FAR - NEAR) and then added to (2 x NEAR * FAR) / (FAR - NEAR). This is what's written to the Z value. And the W component is the original depth/z value of the vertex in eye/camera space. I'm trying to have depth values in the depth buffer more evenly spaced out, so I would like to modify this. The problem is that I'm not sure which of these values are used by the implementation for 1) clipping the triangles, and 2) proper perspective interpolation.

Idea 1): Write the NDC (-1, 1) in x and y, and the depth value I want in z, and set the w to 1 so the division by 1 doesn't affect the values. Problem: clipping has to be done in clip space, which that isn't. Also the hardware uses W for perspective correct interpolation? And W ALWAYS has to be the depth?

Idea 2): Modify the original projection matrix. What would happen if I modify the
(NEAR + FAR)/(FAR - NEAR) + (2 x NEAR * FAR) / (FAR - NEAR) to something more suitable? What would this break? The hardware uses the W for perspective correct interpolation, right? What does it use z component for? Perspective correct clipping?

Idea 3): The way I've this handled in some uses is to use logarithmic depth buffer, in the cases I've seen it requires writing to the depth buffer in the fragment shader, but this completely gets rid of early z-depth test optimisation and isn't ideal.

Comment: If your goal is to produce a depth buffer with more evenly spaced depth values, isn't your problem solved with a reverse-z depth buffer?

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio No pretty sure not. If by that you mean 1 - depth, just so that 1 is near plane and 0 is far plane. The distribution is ridiculous using the normal formula to make the projection matrix.

Comment: Have you researched this through? The reverse-z depth buffer virtually eliminates z-fighting at larger distances, and your far plane can be as far away as you like without affecting depth precision. All graphics APIs (DirectX/Vulkan/OpenGL) implement a reverse-z buffer quite easily and the research seems to be unanimous as to its efficacy.